# How to use Quotation mark in translation CSV Magento 2

Tags: magento2, csv, language

I'm trying to change the following in a custom translation file but can't get it to work:

> "Check "Remember Me" to access your shopping cart on this computer even if you are not signed in."

to

> "Check "Remember Me" to access your shopping basket on this computer even if you are not signed in."

I have tried the following:

> "Check \"Remember Me\" to access your shopping basket on this computer even if you are not signed in."
>
> "Check ""Remember Me"" to access your shopping basket on this computer even if you are not signed in."
>
> "Check \"\"Remember Me\"\" to access your shopping basket on this computer even if you are not signed in."

It's in a csv file that has other translations in that do work

Comment: Can you please provide what steps you tried follow to do the above mentioned changes ?

Comment: I have now added what I have tried.  This sentence isn't affected by  a JS file is it? It's part of the "Whats this" tool tip for "Remember Me"

Comment: Try `\"Remember Me\"` ... backslash `(\)` to escape the double quotes

Comment: Sorry just edited they should have been \

Comment: Try `"Check \"Remember Me\" to access your shopping basket on this computer even if you are not signed in."`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did a little bit of digging for this found it here:

vendor/magento/module-persistent/i18n/en_US.csv

The line states:

`"Check &quot;Remember Me&quot; to access your shopping cart on this computer when you are logged out","Check &quot;Remember Me&quot; to access your shopping cart on this computer when you are logged out"`

So you need to change this in your custom CSV file:

`"Check &quot;Remember Me&quot; to access your shopping cart on this computer when you are logged out","Check &quot;Remember Me&quot; to access your shopping basket on this computer when you are logged out"`

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 19):

you have to double the quotes in your language file.

```
"Check ""Remember Me"" to access","Check ""Remember Me"" to access"
|      \|           \|          |
|       |            |          |
|       |------------|          |
|              |                |     
|           will be             |
|         transformed           |
|         to one "              |
|-------------------------------|
           |
           |
     used by the csv format as delimiter
```

Comment: Interesting approach.. why couldn't they simply have escaped it?

Comment: The safest way is to check how the string to be translated looks where it is defined. If the string contains `&quot;`, use `&quot;` in translation file. If it contains `"` then use `""` in translation file. The double quotes is due to RFC-4180, paragraph "If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote."